# Change the name of an injected service in grails

Tags: grails, service

Can't seem to find info on this, if you have some, please point me to the right thread/post/link!

I have a service, lets say it's called 'SomeServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange'. Of course the normal way to use services is to allow grails to inject them using either typless or typed notation:

```
class SomeClass{
    //...
    def someServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange
    //...
}
```

-- or --

```
class SomeClass{
    //...
    SomeServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange someServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange
    //...
}
```

What I would like to do is rename the service to something shorter, but only where I'm using it, as I cannot change the name of the actual service. I tried using 'as' notation like you do with imports, and I tried changing the name in the typed declaration, but none of these things seem to work. Is this possible?

I tried something like this:

```
class SomeClass{
    //...
    def someServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange as SS
    //and I tried
    def SomeServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange SS
    //no joy
    //...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use autowire by type. By default grails uses autowire by name and hence you have to declare the service with the same name as the bean.

Here's example

```
class FooController {

  boolean byName = false  //set autowire by type
  SomeReallyLongService service

}
```

1. You have to define a boolean variable byName and set it to false
2. You can not use def but must use the actual type of the service when declaring the service
3. It will enable autowire by type for whole controller, so all other dependencies will also be autowired by type

It is explained [here](http://grails.org/Advanced+Topics)

Update:
It is even possible to use Autowired annotation along with Qualifier.

Example:

```
class MyController {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myServiceWithDifferntName")
  def someService

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm surprised I didn't bump into that while searching. I think this is the method I will use, though it is a shame I cannot do both (wire by name for a, b, and c, and manually wire by type for d for example).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a new bean via `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    ss(SomeServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange)
}
```

You can then inject it normally:

```
class SomeClass {
    //...
    def ss
    //...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to autowire by type instead of creating duplicate  beans ?

Comment: Ah, ok this is a good solution too. I think I will end up using the auto wire by type method, but this seemingly obvious technique (hindsight is 20/20) is a great tool to have. I think I have another situation where this will work really well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you don't want to use autowire by type through the whole controller, nor do you want to add a custom bean for some reason, is to add a simple method to your controllers where you need the service, like so:

```
def someServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange
def getSS() { someServiceWithAReallyLongNameICannotChange }
```

Then you could reference the service using `ss.someMethod()` anywhere within that controller.

However, this still requires you to add a chunk of code for every controller you use this service, or you will have inconsistent naming of the service.

(Personally, I think that *doelleri*'s method is the best, since it allows you to be consistent in naming without modifying individual classes.)

Comment: Yes of course! Why didn't I think of that. I used a technique like this in java all the time, it just didn't compute for some reason. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it's not working for me on Grails 3, did this by doing

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
...
@Autowired
PaymentStrategyService paymentStrategySvc
```